# slice inside of a struct

Tags: json, api, go

I'm trying to create a json file that has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "targets": [ "aaaa", "bbbb" ],
    "labels": {
      "env": "dev",
      "job": "cadvisor"
    }
  }
]
```

So far, I have defined two structs:

```
type Label struct {
    Job string `json:"job"`
    Env string `json:"env"`
}

type Target struct {
    Targets []string `json:"targets"`
    Labels  Label    `json:"labels"`
}
```

But when I do a POST request, I'm getting an error: `json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Target.targets of type []string`.

And this is the function that I am using to get the json data from the POST request:

```
func addNewTarget(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //define new struct to hold new json from POST request
    var t Target
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
}
```

I can't really understand what I am doing wrong here. I'm assuming this has to do with me appending to a slice that is not initialized anywhere, but to be honest with you, I do not have an idea on how to do that. Could anyone give me some pointers?

This is the curl that I am using:

`curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"targets":"localhost", "labels": { "job": "job1", "env":"prod"}}'`

Comment: The error is telling you that in the input JSON, the `target` field is a string, not an array, but you are trying to unmarshal it to one.

Comment: The example json does not match the error. Please provide the json you *actually* want to decode, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've added the curl that I am using.

Comment: @dywan666 A string and an array of strings is not the same thing. Look at the top comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Burak commented, shouldn't your curl command be ...

```sh
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"targets":["localhost"], "labels": { "job": "job1", "env":"prod"}}'
```

Comment: It should, I feel so dumb right now. Thanks!